# How to send HTTP POST request with gziped content with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, http, post, gzip, alamofire

I'm working on a iOS app to post about 2000 array of objects to server. I'm doing an experiment. I used

```
let param: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "OwnerEmail": document.fromOwner!.email as AnyObject,
    "UTCTimeStamp": document.utcTimeStamp as AnyObject,
    "Latitude": document.latitude as AnyObject,
    "Longitude": document.longitude as AnyObject,
    ...
]

customAlamofireManager.request(<ServerURL>, 
    method: .post, 
    parameters: param, 
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default, 
    headers: headers)
```

to post 1 object. But now I'm posting 2000 or more, I'm thinking using [gzip](https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift) to compress the array of objects and then upload to check network efficiency. But I don't know how to do that using Alamofire. 
I found this [link](http://allocinit.io/ios/gzip-alamofire/).

However Alamofire has no enum ParameterEncoding in the latest version now. Some other links suggest use Alamofire.upload.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this below code to pass the parameters for POST request using Alamofire SDK:

```
 let param: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "OwnerEmail": document.fromOwner!.email as AnyObject,
        "UTCTimeStamp": document.utcTimeStamp as AnyObject,
        "Latitude": document.latitude as AnyObject,
        "Longitude": document.longitude as AnyObject,
        ...
    ]
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    do{
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: .prettyPrinted)
        request.httpBody = data

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in


            print(response)

        }

    } catch
        {
       }
```

This will works for you to resolve your above issue.

Comment: I have about a few thousands of those param, want to compress it first, then post. I can successfully post just 1 param. Thanks.